# Problem using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

Tags: vb.net

In the following vb code, an error occurs in the line where I try to put the Subject and the sender emailadress in a listbox. If I just put the Subject in the box, it works fine, but when I also take the sender emailadress, I am getting this error: 0x8000404 (E_ABORT)).
I cannot figure out why??

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim oApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        Dim NS As [NameSpace] = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim mBox As Folder = oApp.Session.Folders("Migatronic Consultant Access")
        Dim Indfolder As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder = mBox.Folders("Indbakke")
        Dim ProcFolder As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder = Indfolder.Folders("Processed")
        MsgBox(ProcFolder.EntryID)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each msg In ProcFolder.Items
            If TypeOf msg Is MailItem Then
                Dim wrkmsg As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(msg, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
                Dim tstmsg As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
                'wrkmsg = CType(msg, MailItem)
                tstmsg = NS.GetItemFromID(wrkmsg.EntryID)
                'ListBox1.Items.Add(wrkmsg.Subject)
                'If wrkmsg IsNot Nothing AndAlso wrkmsg.SenderName IsNot Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add(wrkmsg.Subject & " " & wrkmsg.SenderName)
                If wrkmsg IsNot Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add(wrkmsg.Subject & " " & wrkmsg.SenderEmailAddress.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As system.Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have tried asking the Microsoft CoPilot, but none of the suggestions would solve the problem.

I expected to get an emailadress, but I must be missing something :-(

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, I have done a lot of seaching before asking this question, but until now I found nothing.

Comment: Using the debugger, check if `wrkmsg.SenderEmailAddress` is `Nothing` or not.

Comment: First I am sorry for the late response, but I have been ill for some days and have not been in the office.
If I try to test it like this 'If IsNothing(wrkmsg.SenderEmailAddress) Then MsgBox("It is nothing")', the same error occurs, so it is a bit difficult to test I think??

Comment: It is critical to programming that you learn how to use the debugger of your IDE. Put a breakpoint on the line throwing the exception, and then check the value of `wrkmsg.SenderEmailAddress`

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood you. Yes I have tried to put breakpoints more than one place in the code, and everytime I check the value of wrkmsg.SenderEmailAdress it has thrown an exeption. The same happens if I try to use SenderName. I tried to iterate through all the mails in the folder by using the old "On Error Resume Next", but none of them gives me the SenderEmailAdress. It is as if it simply does not work with Outlook 365. I have also tried to check on the SenderEmailType and if that was EX then I tried to get the wrkmsg.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress, but that also fails.

Comment: Try to leave ToString.

Comment: @Black cat: I tried both with and without the ToString, but still it throws an exception

Comment: So no one is able to tell why it fails or what I am doing wrong???